# Align two faces without math

Tags: modeling

I'm a complete beginner in **Blender** (altough I'm quite experienced in CAD use) and I'm trying to build an *complex* object starting from two solid bodies.
This's the current placement.

[image]

What I want to do now is to merge the three bodies into a single one joining them by the facing surfaces without any deformation. The objects are already aligned on X an Z axis I just need to join them. I bet there's a way to do this without having to calculate the offset. There's probably a way to select surfaces to align/match and let Blender do the *hard* work. I looked around but I found only examples to join surfaces by creating another set of faces or trough deformation of existing faces. Once aligned I would like to merge bodies to have just one single item in scene hierarchy.

**-- EDIT --**

BTW the result solid shoud be this one:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 3D viewports menu bar, enable snapping by click the Magnet Icon. Next to the icon, in the *snapping to* dropdown menu. Select *Face*, since you want to snap to a face and choose *Active*.

[image: snap]

By moving an object in object mode you can snap its origin to other faces. Go into edit mode <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>, go into face mode <kbd>3</kbd>. Select the face which you want to snap (it gets highlighted as the active face) and add all other faces which you want to move to the selection. (Box Select or <kbd>A</kbd>)

Press <kbd>G</kbd> to move the geometry and by hovering over the face of the other object with mouse, the face snaps to it. Press <kbd>X</kbd> during the <kbd>G</kbd> operation to constrain the movement to the X-Axis.

[image: process demo]

---

If you want to automatically modify the orientation while snapping to an oblique face, check *Align Rotation to Target* in the snapping settings.

[image: align rotation to target]

The position the objects center at the face you wish to snap and snap it in object mode.

[image: snapping process with orientation]

Comment: very good thx. What if I have to snap the object to one the oblique faces?

Comment: You want to know how to rotate the object automatically?

Comment: uhm.. yes? I need to place an elment on on of the front faces (but not the vertical one)

Comment: Sorry, my english vocabulary didn't include oblique yet as I was reading your comment. I added an edit. That method isn't very practical, but I know of no other. When snapping with orientation the objects sadly always use Z as up and not the closest axis.

Comment: it's enough practical for my pourposes :-) thnx again.

Comment: one last question: is possibile, along snapping, or after that to costraint placement to a specific offset from a corner of the landing face?

Comment: Not that I know of. But perhaps someone else. Feel free to open up a new question! Preferably with a good illustration of the process like in this question.