# Aligning the faces of two models

Tags: objects, transforms, faces, snapping

I have two models, for simplicity let's say an [Octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron) and an [Icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron), and I'd like to move the Octahedron so that a particular one of its faces aligns with a particular face of the Icosahedron, so that I can then join them into one model.

[image]

I am fine with translating, rotating or scaling either model, I just don't want to distort them.

Once I've got them aligned, joining the faces is the easy bit. I can also do the scaling pretty easily since I just measure two edges find the correct ratio and scale one model by that value. I can do all that, but I don't know how to move them so they perfectly align. Trying to do so manually they are still misaligned after tweaking things. I would like to do this operation more than 50 times in total, and even though I will likely get better with time, it just doesn't seem like a viable method.

[image: Misaligned models]

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172839/align-two-faces-without-math) is very similar but it's constrained to simply sliding parallel faces the right distance along an axis. My faces are not parallel and need a more complex set of transforms to align them.

In short I'd like some way to take two congruent or similar faces and translate one of the models so that the two faces are incident. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Do you need the faces to be scaled to one another, too, or just centered?

Comment: @RobinBetts I can measure the lengths of the edges and calculate the scaling factor myself, so in principle I don't need it, although it would save some time if I could do it all in one.

Comment: It's a paid solution so I'm not posting it as an answer, but I'd recommend the "3 Points Align" addon: https://blendermarket.com/products/3-points-align You just choose three points on two objects and it aligns them, with an option to scale ("Match Distances"). There's also the free MeshAlignPlus addon: https://github.com/egtwobits/mesh_mesh_align_plus/releases which works, but much harder to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have these 2 objects with their target faces marked in blue. These are the faces to which the objects should snap & align. You can enable *Face Project* type of *Snapping* with the following settings shown below. Make sure *Transform Options* is set to *Affect Only Origins*.

[image]

Select an object, say the Octahedron, and press <kbd>G</kbd> to move its *Origin* and then hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while moving it to the target face. Notice how the *Origin* starts to snap and point into the *Face Normal*'s direction. Then click <kbd>LMB</kbd> or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. Press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to rotate the *Origin* 180 degrees along the local X axis. Again click <kbd>LMB</kbd> or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. Now the Origin's local Z-axis is facing in the opposite direction relative to the target *Face Normal*.

[image]

Then untick *Affect Only Origins* in the *Transform Options* to return to normal object transform mode. Select the object and move it over the other object's target face and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to make it snap to that target face. Then click <kbd>LMB</kbd> or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. Notice how the 2 blue surfaces perfectly align.

[image]

If you need the faces to perfectly align at their centers you can use the *Cursor to Selected* on the target face in *Edit Mode* and the *Selection to Cursor* in *Object Mode* using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on the Octahedron and then do a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to Selected* on the Icosahedron's Target face in *Edit Mode*. Then once you have snapped the Octahedron to the Icosahedron, you select the Octahedron and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Selection to Cursor* so the center of the Octahedron's target face aligns to the center of the Icosahedron's target face. You can rotate the Octahedron on the local Z-axis to adjust rotation using <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: This does not work in Blender 3.6. A smile sphere snaps but when I have a complex object such as a wing with more surfaces it fails to snap.
It is absolutely ridiculous that Blender can’t align the faces of two objects without a simple select the faces and align

Comment: @Carlos500 i'm not sure what you mean by "smile sphere", but can you have a look at [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298446/how-can-i-set-the-z-axis-rotation-of-a-text-to-face-a-face-which-is-i-selected) and if that also does not resolve it, can you post a new question with detailed description of the problem and reference this thread so we can have a look :) and also add a blend file with a simple setup that reproduces your issue.