# What is the best method to "glue" a mesh on top of a face?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, faces

I'm making a super simple club as a study and I've modeled a stud that I'd like to add to the model. I'd like to know how can I "glue" this stud in the faces of the club in a way that it follows the z axis angle where the face is. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: did u try parent?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: If the 2 objects are separated, join them with Ctrl J, or parent the small piece to the big one with Ctrl P. If they are part of the same object but you want the 2 meshes to be merged you need to do a bit of modeling. Please give more details on what you want to do

Comment: Try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282835/142292

Comment: To get them to line up, investigate Snapping set to Face. When the 'stud' is where you want it use Ctrl P > Object (Keep Transform).