# Snapping a Object to a face with a set direction?

Tags: modeling, objects, snapping, text-object

I use Blender 3.5 and I try to add numbers to dice faces (standard 7 piece fantasy set for 3D printing).

What I tried is using the snapping tool, setting the origin to center of mass and made it snap to the center of the faces (with aligning the rotation). That worked really well for the cube but for the other shapes not so much...

My problem is the numbers (already converted to mesh) will align seemingly random on the face, but because they are numbers I need them in a certain direction on the face. Of course I can rotate them by hand, but that is really hard because depending on the font.

Is there a way to select a vertex and get Blender to rotate my numbers so they are oriented towards that?

I thought about trying to use GeoNodes for that, but that is too far out of reach atm. I am just too new to modeling and Blender and have 0 experience in programming.

Help please.

Edit:
these are the standard shapes of the dice:

[image: Standard 7 piece fanatsy dice]

So what I now need is numbers on them. To make them readable I need all of them with the top of the number facing towards the point of the shape. Like the 1 in this exaple. But this is what happens when I just snap them on the face (centered):

[image]

[image]

I can rotate the numbers, but for the 6 and the 9 e.g. that is super hard to decide by hand.
So what I need is help how to make them, in this example, all face the top.

In the end they all should look something like this:

[image: Finished set of dice, dice and photo made by me]

Comment: Hello and welcome. I'm not sure I understand the problem. Could you provide some images that illustrtate what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe this can help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282835/142292

Comment: you can try to do the opposite (at least for some of the dices): I mean snapping them onto a horizontal plane.

Comment: @lemon I don't think I understand how that would help.

Comment: could you share a blend file with 2 or 3 dice models, (and numbers) for test purpose? Please use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: This is a link the blender file in blend exchange with the shapes (which are super basic, since except the d10 it's all just primitives). I will add the numbers in a moment [link](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NYPo5L4W/)

Comment: @lemon  And the numbers: [link](https://blend-exchange.com/b/nQdaKMzx/)

Comment: ok, that could be done... but you want to 3D print... how do you imagine the cut to be done? https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7SCK.png

Comment: How did you do that? Did you have to fiddle around? Is that a UVProject? For my D6 (cubes) I converted the numbers to a mesh, extruded the faces and just booleaned them. (Not sure that is still proper English) That worked quite nicely for those. But yeah the otheres were .... no fun at all...

Comment: Yep a bit long to do. I've done it as I said previously: previously snap a dice face to an horizontal plane then adjust position/rotation for the numbers. As the dice face is horizontal, this is much easier to do, even if the rotation on Z is not aligned.