Where/how can I see what the orientation of a face is (in degrees)?
I want to be able to rotate a mesh, so that its rotation aligns with that of a specific face on another mesh. Is there any way for me to see the rotation of a face expressed in terms of degrees and not just a line that tracks from the middle of the face?

I remember seeing some kind of “follow orientation of target” thing, probably in the snap menu?

The problem with snap mode is that it becomes very finicky with complex meshes.

Fair enough. If this isn’t an option, I think you should post it on the right click select forum as a feature request.

Can you try this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282835/142292
